# Calcular o seno pela expansão em série de Taylor

Tags: python, while

Escreva um programa que calcule uma aproximação para o seno conforme a equação abaixo:

```
seno(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + ... + x^n/n!
```

Sendo que `x` e `n` são números inteiros informados pelo usuário. Se `n` for par o programa deve informar "n inválido".

Consegui escrever isso:

```
x=int(input(">"))
n=int(input(">"))
fat=1
n00=1
n0=1
n01=1
d=0
s=0

if n%2==0:
    print("n inválido")
else:
    while n0<=n:
        while n01<=n0:
            fat=fat*n01
            n01=n01+1
        d=(x**n0)/fat
        s=d-s
        n0=n0+2
    print(s)
```

O calculo dá certo, porém em módulo.
Sei que existem maneiras mais simples, mas gostaria de consertar sem mudar muito.

Comment: Os nomes das suas variáveis não são nada intuitivas. Poderia descrever o que é cada uma e qual a função delas no código?

Comment: x e n são as variaveis da equação, fat é de fatorial, d para calcular cada fração individualmente, e s de seno vai recebendo tudo, o problema esta nisso, pois os resultados dão certo, porém em módulo

Answer (score 5):

Eu realmente não consegui entender o seu código, achei bastante confusos os nomes das variáveis, ficando bem difícil entender o que é cada coisa dentro do código.

Se você perceber, a sequência dada é o cálculo da função seno a partir da expansão pela série de Taylor, dada pela forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obviamente que computacionalmente será impossível (ou inviável) somar infinitos termos, então pegamos uma quantidade finita que seja suficientemente próxima ao resultado desejado. Essa quantidade será denotada por `n`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor dentro da somatória é o que chamamos de termo geral da série e só depende de `x` e `i`, então podemos defini-lo no Python:

```
from math import factorial

def termo_geral(x, i):
    return ((-1)**i / factorial(2*i+1)) * (x**(2*i+1))
```

Porém, devemos calcular o valor a partir do termo geral para cada valor de `i` de 0 até `n-1`, então podemos montar a sequência:

```
def termos(x, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield termo_geral(x, i)
```

E, finalmente, o cálculo do seno será a soma de todos os termos da série:

```
seno = sum(termos(x, n))
```

Assim, podemos generalizar o cálculo para apenas uma função:

```
from math import factorial, radians

def seno(x, n=7):
    x = radians(x)

    def termo_geral(x, i):
        return ((-1)**i / factorial(2*i+1)) * (x**(2*i+1))

    def termos(x, n):
        for i in range(n):
            yield termo_geral(x, i)

    return sum(termos(x, n))
```

A entrada da função deve ser o ângulo em graus, bastando fazer `seno(30)` para obter o seno de 30°. Um teste de que o código calcula corretamente a série é apresentado a seguir, onde se compara o valor calculado pela função definida e pela função nativa do pacote `math` com um erro menor que 0.00001:

```
from math import radians, isclose, sin

for angle in {0, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 180, 230, 270, 320, 360}:
    assert isclose(
        seno(angle, 21), 
        sin(radians(angle)), 
        abs_tol=1e-5
    )
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HatefulRundownPaint) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/qGMocw) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/8ad92c350cff8ed1b509b2a760eb4ef0)</sup>

A ausência de saída indica que todos os *asserts* passaram.