# Como implementar a função cosseno usando série de Taylor em Python?

Tags: python, for

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema:
[image: EXERCÍCIO]

Até então fiz o seguinte código:

```
import math

def cos(x, n):

    soma = 1
    formula = (((-1)**n)*(x**2*n))/math.factorial(2*n)
    for i in range(n):
        soma += formula
    return soma
```

Alguém pode dizer se está correto? Se não, como faço pra corrigir?

Comment: Uma opção para evitar o cálculo `((-1)**n)`é fazer: `sinal = 1` fora do loop e dentro do loop fazer: `sinal = -sinal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está (mas quase). Da forma que fez:

```py
def cos(x, n):

    soma = 1
    formula = (((-1)**n)*(x**2*n))/math.factorial(2*n)
    for i in range(n):
        soma += formula
    return soma
```

O valor de `formula` será avaliado apenas uma única vez, com `n` igual ao parâmetro passado. Você precisa avaliar esse valor para cada item da sua sequência. Fora isso, a sua fórmula deve depender do valor de `i` (que é o `k` na somatória), não de `n`. E se irá fazer o `range` iniciando em 0, você não deve iniciar o valor de `soma` com 1, mas sim com 0, pois é o elemento neutro da adição.

Quanto à fórmula, há apenas um problema de prioridade de operadores. Quando você escreve `x**2*n` será x²n e não x<sup>2n</sup> como seria o esperado; para contornar isso você deve adicionar os parenteses.

```
import math

def cos(x, n):
  formula = lambda k: (-1)**k * x**(2*k) / math.factorial(2*k)
  soma = 0

  for k in range(n+1):
    soma += formula(k)

  return soma
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MiniScaredJavabeans) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MPhnlK)</sup>

Para conferir se está certo, basta comparar o valor retornado com a função `math.cos`:

```py
assert math.isclose(cos(0.5, 10), math.cos(0.5))
assert math.isclose(cos(-0.5, 10), math.cos(-0.5))
assert math.isclose(cos(0.0, 10), math.cos(0.0))
assert math.isclose(cos(1.0, 10), math.cos(1.0))
```

Se ocorrer um `AssertionError` é porque algum valor saiu errado.

Utilizando geradores e a função `sum`, sua função poderia ser reduzida a uma linha:

```py
import math

def cos(x, n):
  return sum((-1)**k * x**(2*k) / math.factorial(2*k) for k in range(n+1))
```

Esse processo é o que conhecemos por expansão por séries de Taylor e já respondi isso para o cálculo do seno em:

- [Calcular o seno pela expansão em série de Taylor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/331393/5878)

Sobre o processo de associar uma série matemática com estruturas da programação, você pode ler:

- [Qual a melhor maneira de representar um Loop em matemática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/379364/5878)

Comment: Valeu!!! Eu cheguei até a encontrar a sua resposta, mas já tinha postado aqui, valeu mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

Está muito boa a conta, a única coisa que eu faria seria isolar o "x²k"

```
formula = (((-1)**n)*(x**2*n))/math.factorial(2*n) # o teu
formula = (((-1)**n)*(x**(2*n)))/math.factorial(2*n) #isolado
```

Assim evita qualquer má interpretação ou ambiguidade.

Comment: Tem mais problemas no código dele. O cálculo está fora do loop. Não é só acertar a precedência. A resposta do @Woss está correta.